# what card is used while the sqaure is using in the production mode?

Tags: oauth, square-connect, square

I'm integrating the sqaure api's with golang using  production mode and the sandbox mode. Using Sandbox mode to add the card of a customer there are test cards we have to use. But in production mode I'm using the same test card but it will give the error that `the card is invalid`.

My expected output is `success response` that I have successfully added the customer card using production mode. But I'm facing the error given below:-

```
{
  "errors": [
    {
        "category": "INVALID_REQUEST_ERROR",
        "code": "NOT_FOUND",
        "detail": "Resource not found.",
        "field": "card_nonce"
    }
  ]
}
```

Please don't say pass a valid nonce. I'm already passing a valid nonce I tested it on the sandbox mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Test cards will not work in production, only sandbox. You will need to use real credit cards to test payments (and other endpoints) in production.

Comment: Can I do transaction of 1$ using square?

Comment: Yes! Additionally, businesses located in the United States or Canada can set monetary amounts as low as 1 cent.